# How to understand zero elements in CG coefficient table?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, representation-theory

I understand the standard theory of angular momentum and the reps. of SU(2). I found there are some zero elements in CG coefficient table. I can derive them by using the recurrence relations between CG coefficients.But I am wondering is there any physical picture rather than mathematical derivation behind that. Namely, I am wondering is there any perspectives due to symmetry or whatever to argue the zero elements in CG table?

[image: CG coefficient table from Griffiths' QM textbook]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a cute question.  You have inadvertently opened an interesting can of worms.

Why some CGs have zeroes is an ongoing research topic.  In some cases the reason is trivial.  The CGs $C^{jm_3}_{j_1m_1;j_2m_2}$ are $0$ when the triangularity condition
$\vert j_1-j_2\vert \le j \le j_1+j_2$ is not met.  There is also the condition on the magnetic number: the CG is $0$ unless $m_1+m_2=m_3$.

There are also some symmetry considerations.  Since
$$
C^{lm_3}_{j_1m_1;j_2m_2}=(-1)^{j_1+j_2-j_3}C^{j,-m_3}_{j_1,-m_1;j_2,-m_2}
\tag{1}
$$
it follows that $C^{l0}_{l_10;l_20}=0$ whenever $l_1+l_2-l_3$ is odd.  Note that Eq.(1) is valid in general but, if $m_i=0$, then the angular momenta must be integers hence the specialization from $j_i\to l_i$ in $C^{l0}_{l_10;l_20}=0$.  This is the case of your question.  These CGs are $0$ because of parity arguments, which can be seem using combination of spherical harmonics.

Indeed:
$$
Y^{l_1}_{m_1}(\theta,\varphi)Y^{l_2}_{m_2}(\theta,\varphi)
=\sum_{l_3} \sqrt{\frac{(2l_1+1)(2l_2+1)}{4\pi(2l+1)}}C^{l0}_{l_10;l_20}C^{lm_3}_{l_1m_1;l_2m_2} Y^{l_3}_{m_3}(\theta,\varphi)\, .
$$
The parity of a spherical harmonics $Y^{l_1}_{m_1}(\theta,\varphi)$ is $(-1)^{l_1}$ so the left hand side has parity $(-1)^{l_1+l_2}$ hence the right hand side must have the same parity for all $m_1,m_2,m_3$.  The parity requirement is then enforced by the CG $C^{l0}_{l_10;l_20}$.

More interestingly, there are "accidental" zeros, the origin of which are not always clear.   To declutter the notation I will use
$$
C^{jm_3}_{j_1m_1;j_2m_2}:= \left\langle\begin{array}{cc|c}
j_1&j_2&j_3\\
m_1&m_2&m_3\end{array}\right\rangle
$$

In Table 1 of

> Srinivasa Rao, K., 1985. A note on the classification of the zeros of
> angular momentum coefficients. *Journal of Mathematical Physics*,
> *26*(9), pp.2260-2261,

some accidental zeroes are listed and explained in terms of subgroup chains.

In

> Heim, T.A., Hinze, J. and Rau, A.R.P., 2009. Some classes of ‘nontrivial zeroes’ of angular momentum addition coefficients. *Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and Theoretical*, *42*(17), p.175203.

the authors show that CGs of the type
$$
 \left\langle\begin{array}{cc|c}
 d^2 & 2 d^2-d & d^2 \\
 \frac{1}{2} (d-1) (d+2) & \frac{1}{2} (1-d) (d+2) & 0\end{array}\right\rangle
$$
are $0$ for $d=1,2,3$.  The $d=3$ is may be due to the vanishing of some quadrupole coupling in nuclear physics, but it's not clear if there's a physics-only reason why this coupling should vanish.

In

> Brudno, S. and Louck, J.D., 1985. Nontrivial zeros of weight 1 3 j and 6 j coefficients: Relation to Diophantine equations of equal sums of like powers. *Journal of Mathematical Physics*, *26*(9), pp.2092-2095.

the authors show that CGs of the type
$$
 \left\langle\begin{array}{cc|c}
\frac{u+x}{2} & \frac{v+y}{2} & \frac{1}{2}
   (u+v+x+y-2) \\
 \frac{x-u}{2} & \frac{y-v}{2} & \frac{1}{2} (x+y-u-v)\end{array}\right\rangle
$$
are $0$ whenever the integers $x,y,u,v$ satisfy $(x+u)(y-v)=(x-u)(y+v)$.  A non-trivial instance of this is $x=2,y=16,u=1,v=8$, which gives
$$
 \left\langle\begin{array}{cc|c}
 \frac{3}{2} & 12 & \frac{25}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 4 & \frac{9}{2}\end{array}\right\rangle=0\, .
$$
There is apparently no physics-only reason for this type of zeroes.  These papers are just a sample of literature on the topic.

Disclaimer: this answer was **NOT** AI-generated.

Comment: the disclaimer felt like a punch to the gut, honestly. Is this the future of PSE?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I hope not.

Comment: Chatbots are nowhere near as circumspect; the are more likely to hedge and weasel... But they might learn, in time, to fake-use this disclaimer?

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, such zeros are the analog of nodes in continuous antisymmetric functions.

A sufficient condition for zeros for the special $m_1=m_2=m_3=0$ cases is that $j_1+j_2+j_3$ be a an [odd integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-j_symbol#Selection_rules), but this is not necessary, as you may see in the 2×2 table. The [symmetry properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-j_symbol#Symmetry_properties) of the 3-j symbols are very rich; see, e.g., $j_1=j_2=3/2$, $j_3=2$, $m_1=m_2=1/2$, $m_3=1$.

Ultimately, such zeros are due to antisymmetry in the spherical basis. When you compose two spins, starting from the highest possible $m_3$, symmetric, and descending by a lowering operator, you do not change this symmetry at the lower rung, so there must be a new, antisymmetric, state orthogonal to the original symmetric one, and so on. Symmetric irreps intercalate with the antisymmetric ones, and the antisymmetric ones necessarily vanish at zero *m* s, for example.

An easy way to see this is in the Clebsch resolution of the composition (tensoring) of two three-vectors, $\vec a$ and $\vec b$, resolving to a symmetric traceless rank 2-tensor, an antisymmetric axial vector, and a symmetric scalar, of  spins 2; 1;0, respectively,
$$
T_{ij}={a_ib_j + a_j b_i\over 2}-\delta_{ij} {a_kb_k\over 3}    ,\\
A_{ij}= {a_ib_j - a_j b_i\over 2} =\epsilon^{ijk}\left (\epsilon_{krs}{a_rb_s - a_s b_r\over 2}  \right ) ,\\
S_{ij}= {\delta_{ij}\over 3}  a_kb_k   ,
$$
all mutually orthogonal.

It is evident that $A_{33}=0$, as you see in your 1×1 CG table.